# How to start and stop scripts using another script?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, led

I don't have a lot of experience coding so I'm sorry if this has been answered before; I couldn't find anything that helped.

I just completed a project on a Raspberry Pi that runs some RGB LED strips via PWM. I have a program that runs the lights and works fine with a few different modes (rainbow shifting, strobe, solid color) but with each new mode I add the program get longer and more convoluted. I would like to have each separate mode be its own script that gets started or stopped by a sort of master script. That way I could easily add a new mode by simply writing a separate program and adding it to the list on the master script instead of mucking around inside a giant program with everything in it and hoping I don't break something. I guess what I want is a simple way to start a python script with some specific setting (Determined by variables passed from the master script) and be able to kill that script when the master script receives the command to change modes.

Comment: SO isn't an advice forum; Advice can go out of date. What have you tried so far? Please show your work so we can help you.

Comment: Why don't you separate all the code that does the logic into it's own module/modules and then have a master script that imports the necessary functions and handles the orchestrating logic? Running separate scripts as subprocesses sounds overly complicated.

Comment: you may create a python script & import it yo your main script. , this may help you https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: You can use `subprocess.Popen` to run and later kill other programs... incluing other python programs.

Comment: From your description I think that importing scripts as needed is a particularly bad idea. This is one of the reasons we shy away from open ended questions... some people fail to agree with me!

Comment: @tdelaney using subprocesses, or even some full-blown task manager like `celery` would make sense if you actually have independent tasks, but it seems like the OP just wants to switch different LED modes from a single master script. To me, that sounds like the job of separate functions not separate processes.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - I knew that was going to happen! Consider a program where you could drop custom flash patterns into some subdirectory and run them. Its common to have executables that you re-run to apply different flash patterns to LEDs. I've used them on server back-panels. OP clearly stated that he wanted to write custom patterns at any time. Its a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @tdelaney you did call it! But yeah, I see. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your code modulable is indeed a good practice ! If your code is not Objet oriented, the best way is to create another python file (let's call it util.py) in the same directory as your "main". You can simply include util.py with the following command at the beginning of your main code : 
        import util
And then when you want to use a function that you've defined in your util.py file, juste use :
        util.myFunction(param1, param2,...)

Comment: Not a good idea if you want to recode the dependent modules. I think this problem is better handled by running subprocesses.